# Как получить все value у input(не получается)

Tags: jquery

```
$('#download2').click(function(event){

 $("#formtable").each(function (i) {
        console.log($('input[type="text"]').val());
    console.log($('label[for="lastName"]').text());
  });

});
```

Не получается получить все value у input, выводится почему-то одно значение и то, которое не выходил в formtable. А например, label у меня все значения получаются нормально. Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 2):

1. Зачем цикл each по id? id должен быть один на странице.
2. `console.log($('input[type="text"]').val());` - здесь выбираются все инпуты, а не один, поэтому значение выводится одно (либо первое либо последнее, не помню точно)
3. А вот лейбл по-видимому один на странице, поэтому все ок

Вообще нужно более точно описать задачу, так ничего особо не ясно

Comment: Мне нужно пройтись по всей форме, и все данные формы записать в  json, чтобы потом сформировать xml документ в php. Вот такой например, я должен получить json{label1: input1, label2: input 2}

Comment: var mass = $( ":input" ).serializeArray(); Я так сделал))